# What is the purpose of an UML Object Diagram?

Tags: uml, object-diagram

I'd like to clarity something:

As I understand it, the purpose of object diagram is to show relationships among objects. The sequence in which these objects interact is not relevant. *Is this correct?*

If possible, could you provide general comments on the diagram below:

[image: a sample UML Object Diagram]

Comment: somewhat related: This post has got an [instance diagram for state machine GoF pattern](http://reconvolution.blogspot.com/2015/09/chain-of-responsibility-pattern-in-hierarchical-state-machine.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the goal of an object diagram is to show the relationships between a set of objects  (i.e. the links/pointers between them).

The object diagram shows a static snapshot of the system. Objeect diagrams are not useful to show the sequence of events they exchange (not even those that provoke the system to reach the current state represented by the object diagram). You have the interaction diagrams for this. In particular, the collaboration diagram, looks very similar to an object diagram but the "lines" in it represent method calls, not links

Comment: Do you mean that the object diagram is the same as instance diagram?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments about diagram:**

If your purpose is to show interaction between your objects( object sending/receiving mesages)  you should use Sequence or  Communication Diagram. **Actually the diagram you draw is a kind of   Communication Diagram NOT an Object Diagram( in terms of UML jargon).**

IN UML Communication Diagram you can also label methods calls( object interactions) to show their orders.

> Sequence diagrams and Communication
>   Diagrams show same things with
>   different focus ( From a pragmatic
>   view point, they are same). Sequence
>   diagram emphasize order of messages,
>   Communication Diagrams emphasize 
>   collobrators  more clearly.
>
> *Object diagram rarely used and they show static relationship between(
>   there is no time) objects. They
>   generally used for making Class
>   diagram more concrete when the static
>   relationships are complex in Class
>   diagram.*